# Absolute and conditional convergence of a series with cos

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\ln n)^6}{\sqrt n}\cos \frac{\pi n} 6$$
Conditional convergence is easy :
Let $\alpha = \frac{\pi n}{12}$, then $\cos2\alpha = 1 - 2\sin^2 \alpha$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\ln n)^6}{\sqrt n}\cos\frac{\pi n} n = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\ln n)^6}{\sqrt n} - 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 \alpha}{\sqrt n}$$
First series is divergent and second series is convergent, thus all series is divergent.

But I don't know what to do with absolute convergent. Could you give me any tips?

Comment: Sometimes $\ln^6 n$ means $\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln n)))))$ and sometimes it means $(\ln n)^6.$  I think it's better to avoid that notation except when you say which of those you intend. $\qquad$

Comment: Do you mean $\cos(\pi n)/n$?

Comment: I fixed a mistake. I mean cos(pi*n/6)

Comment: But $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 \frac{\pi n}{12}}{\sqrt{n}}$$ diverges (and if you include the factor $(\ln n)^6$, it diverges a little faster). In fact, by Dirichlet's criterion the original series converges.

Comment: @DanielFischer, i.e in original sereis cos is bounded and leftover part of term is monotonic and -> 0 ?

Comment: Close. The sums $\sum_{n = 1}^N \cos \frac{n\pi}{6}$ are bounded, and $\frac{(\ln n)^6}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to $0$ and is _eventually_ monotonic. It starts with a growing bit at first.

Comment: Yes, this start of series confused me and I didn't use Dirichlet's criterion at once.

Comment: What you called second series is not correct.

Comment: To show that the convergence is conditional,  we write  $$\sum_{n=1}^{6N} \left|\frac{\log^6(n)}{\sqrt n}\cos(\pi n/6)\right| \ge \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log^6(6n)}{\sqrt{6n}}\to \infty\,\,\text{as}\,\,N\to \infty$$